# how to get the data from html table and access each row and coulmn data in php without using database

Tags: php, html

How to get the data of each row and column from HTML table in php and show it in a variable in php with out using the database.how to set the value of unchecked check box and show  the value of unchecked check box in PHP when form is submitted.

Comment: http://php.net/dom good luck

Comment: You could use a simple HTML parser like [Ganon](https://code.google.com/p/ganon/)